# Best OOP Practices PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, oop, structure, overloading

I am creating a word teacher:

I created a database with multiple tables:

```
TblTheme (themeId, name);<br>
TblGroup (groupId, name, themeIdFK);<br>
TblWeek (weekId, week, groupIdFK);<br>
tblWord (wordId, word, weekIdFK);<br>
```

So themeIdFK, groupIdFK and weekIdFK are Foreign keys.

In PHP i want to show all the themes. If a theme is pressed, show all the groups etc..
What classes should i create. (like classes Theme, group, week and word)
and what is the best way to retrieve the data, without overloading the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , if column holds same data , then it should have the same name:

```
Themes (theme_id, name);
Groups (group_id, name, theme_id);
```

Then when you create JOIN , you can write it as

```
SELECT 
   Themes.name AS theme,
   Groups.name AS group
FROM Themes 
LEFT JOIN Groups USING theme_id
```

---

As for you original question :
I would go with classes :

- Teacher - that would be your MVC model
- Word  - used by model, holds you daily word and some additional info about it
- WordMapper - responsible for storing and retrieving instances of Word class

Basically this setup would implement [DataMapper pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

There is no point in making a class per table, because the additional tables are only holding info about the Words. At lest that's how i see it.

Though, I'm not so sure if you need to make a complex App, just for making word-of-day thing .. maybe only as exercise.

Comment: Thats very clear, it will be a rather complex app. So what your saying it is best to store the theme, group and week data in the word class?

Thanks!

Comment: The database storage and application logic are completely different systems. From application's point of view "theme", "group" and "day" are only *constraints* for choosing the word [ `$word = new Word; $mapper = new WordMapper; $mapper->had_group('foobar')->load( $word );` ]. They are not acting like full entities.

Comment: Dear person who downvoted, but did not have enough guts to leave a comment: could you explain, please, what is wrong wit this answer?